# Jquery Find if response contains element

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do you find if the response contains the element form

```
    $.ajax({
        url     : $(this).attr('action'),
        type    : 'POST',
        success : function(response){
            if($(response).find('form').length)
            {
                alert("hii");
            }
        }
    });
```

Form could be the topmost element of the response or somewhere in middle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
        url     : $(this).attr('action'),
        type    : 'POST',
        dataType: 'html', // you should set it 
                          //  if you response send html only
        success : function(response){
            if($(response).filter('form').length)
            {
                alert("hii");
            }
        }
    });
```

**According to update:**

```
        ....
        dataType: 'html',
        success : function(response){
            var container = $('<div/>').append(response);
            if($(container).find('form').length)
            {
                alert("hii");
            }
        }
```

Comment: @WebDeveloper you don't set `dataType: html`. Try with my code and you will get result

Comment: plz see my update to the question ... form may be first/topmost element of the response itself

Comment: @WebDeveloper hi mate, checked your update and update my answer

Comment: also is there a long way of generating $('<div id="dialog-confirm" title="'+ConfirmBox.title+'"><p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>'+confirmbox.message+'</p></div>').appendTo('body');

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    url     : $(this).attr('action'),
    type    : 'POST',
    success : function(response){
        var hasForm = $("<div></div>").append(response).find("form").length > 0;
        if(hasForm)
        {
            alert("hi");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The dataType : 'html' forces jQuery to treat the response as simply html. I'm using the "has" function which will reduce the matched set of elements to only those that contain a form somewhere in them.

```
 $.ajax({
        url     : $(this).attr('action'),
        type    : 'POST',
        dataType : 'HTML',
        success : function(response){
           $(response).has('form').doMoreWorkHere();
        }
    });
```

Alternatively, you can write that shorter by

```
$.post($(this).attr('action'), {}
       function(response){
         $(response).has('form').doMoreWorkHere();
       }, 'html');
```

Answer (score -1):

Where does 'response' come from? What format is it?

I send my returned vars in json:

```
success: function(msg){
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( msg ); 
    alert( obj.VARNAMEHERE );
}
```

Or you could just examine the entire response as opposed to a particular variable. That would give you an idea as to how to traverse the results to find what you're looking for.